# Mod-rewrite; apache rules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?paste=$1 [L]
```

As you can see above it takes `site.com/index.php?paste=pasteID` and turns it into `site.com/pasteID`

Now I would like to know a way where I can edit the paste such like this.

```
site.com/index.php?paste=pasteID&page=edit
site.com/pasteID/edit
```

Is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: Your explanation of your rule is not correct, maybe that is where your confusion comes from: Your rules do this: they internally rewrite a request to `site.com/pasteID` to `site.com/index.php?paste=pasteID&page=edit`. So the other way round. Always look from the _clients_ point of view when configuring the server. Because it is clients requests that are processed by the server. It is not so that the server sends out some rewritten url that might be requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?paste=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/edit$ index.php?paste=$1&page=edit [L]
```

Examples:

- `domain.com/534` -> `index.php?paste=534`
- `domain.com/abc` -> `index.php?paste=abc`
- `domain.com/abc123` -> `index.php?paste=abc123`
- `domain.com/534/edit` -> `index.php?paste=534&page=edit`
- `domain.com/abc/edit` -> `index.php?paste=abc&page=edit`
- `domain.com/abc123/edit` -> `index.php?paste=abc123&page=edit`